# How to resolve error The specified alg value is not allowed in django

Tags: django, python-3.x, jwt

I am trying to decode some JWT string that I have received from an authentication service but I'm getting an error `The specified alg value is not allowed`. What could be the issue? I verified that the algorithim I should use is **HS256**.

When I try to decode the JWT string at https://jwt.io/ it's being decoded.

**code snippet**

```
    try:
        print(jwt_value)
        decoded = jwt.decode(jwt_value, 'secret', algorithms=['HS256'])
        print(decoded)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

**JWT Settings**

```
JWT_AUTH = {
    # 'JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(seconds=36000),
    'JWT_ENCODE_HANDLER':
    'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_encode_handler',

    'JWT_DECODE_HANDLER':
    'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_decode_handler',

    'JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER':
    'sbp.custom_jwt.jwt_payload_handler',

    'JWT_PAYLOAD_GET_USER_ID_HANDLER':
    'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_get_user_id_from_payload_handler',

    'JWT_RESPONSE_PAYLOAD_HANDLER':
    'sbp.custom_jwt.jwt_response_payload_handler',

    'JWT_SECRET_KEY': 'secret',
    'JWT_GET_USER_SECRET_KEY': None,
    'JWT_PUBLIC_KEY': None,
    'JWT_PRIVATE_KEY': None,
    'JWT_ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
    'JWT_VERIFY': True,
    'JWT_VERIFY_EXPIRATION': True,
    'JWT_LEEWAY': 0,
    'JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(seconds=36000),
    'JWT_AUDIENCE': None,
    'JWT_ISSUER': None,

    'JWT_ALLOW_REFRESH': False,
    'JWT_REFRESH_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(days=7),

    'JWT_AUTH_HEADER_PREFIX': 'JWT',
    'JWT_AUTH_COOKIE': None,
}
```

Comment: The header of the token contains `"alg": "HS256"`?

Comment: I can't seem to find it but when I try to print `request.META` this is the minimal relevant data. `{'REQUEST_METHOD':'POST','SERVER_PROTOCOL':'HTTP/1.0','HTTP_HOST':'web','HTTP_CONNECTION':'close','CONTENT_LENGTH':'0','CONTENT_TYPE':'application/json','HTTP_AUTHORIZATION':'JWT eyJhb1Fq-VWeoWUCmjbAM90pNwb6K5Ljiegw4_TdRo','HTTP_USER_AGENT':'PostmanRuntime/7.19.0','HTTP_ACCEPT':'*/*','HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL':'no-cache','HTTP_POSTMAN_TOKEN':'a66-fq2-49e6-8c1e-4fef7c5f643e','HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING':'gzip, deflate'}`

Comment: you said you could decode the jwt at jwt.io? In your request meta I see `JWT eyJhb1Fq-VWeoWUCmjbAM90pNwb6K5Ljiegw4_TdRo`, which is not a valid JWT. What's the output of `print(jwt_value)`?

Comment: I shortened it it was too long anyways let met post it u try.

Comment: I would only need the first part(header) before the first `.`

Comment: eyJhbGciOiJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAxLzA0L3htbGRzaWctbW9yZSNobWFjLXNoYTI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy5taWNyb3NvZnQuY29tL3dzLzIwMDgvMDYvaWRlbnRpdHkvY2xhaW1zL3JvbGUiOiJERVZFTE9QRVIiLCJ1c2VyZnVsbG5hbWUiOiJFcmljIE0gS2FyaW1pIiwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJlcmljIiwidXNlcmlkIjoiMjkiLCJleHAiOjE1NzMyMTA5MzEsImlzcyI6IkVyaWMiLCJhdWQiOiJSZWFkZXJzIn0.agXFPl0Fq-VWeoWUCmjbAM90pNwb6K5Ljiegw4_TdRo

Comment: yes, the alg value should look like this `"alg": "HS256"`. The current value causes the problem.